# Select data from two tables with LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

How to select all data from first table and if in second table row1 == row1 in first table then I need to insert rows from second table to result with LEFT JOIN.

first_table:

```
id    row1     some_data
1     2        test
2     3        test2
```

second_table:

```
id    row1    some_data
1     4       test
2     2       test2
```

Needed result is:

```
id   row1   some_data   id     row1   some_data
1    2      test        2      2      test2
2    3      test2       NULL   NULL   NULL
```

Query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `first_table` AS c 
LEFT JOIN `second_table` AS s ON `c`.`row1` = `s`.`row1`
```

I am sorry for my bad English and thanks in advance.

Comment: Your query looks fine. What is the problem?

Comment: Doesn't the SELECT give you the desired result already?

Comment: take time to express what you need exactly and reedit your question; most users here do not speak English at home, but we make effort to express our ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following LEFT OUTER JOIN should give the desired result. It is important use an alias tables (t1, t2) to designate.

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.row1, t1.some_data, t2.id, t2.row1, t2.some_data
  FROM first_table t1
  LEFT JOIN second_table t2
    ON t1.row1 = t2.row2
ORDER BY t1.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

this is how we can put left join

```
SELECT *
FROM first_table As c
LEFT JOIN second_table AS o ON c.row1 = o.row1
```

you can learn more about left join [here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-left-join.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
SELECT f.*,s.id,s.row1,s.some_data
FROM first_table As f
LEFT JOIN second_table AS s ON f.row1 = s.row1
```